# Adding "Home" at the beginning of breadcrumbs

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, styles, breadcrumbs

I'm having issues formatting the breadcrumbs on my staging site. I had them set up with the correct categories before, but the parent category kept displaying the wrong category (which I did fix, but...). The fix caused the "home" option to disappear. I don't know any php and have been trying without success to figure out how to add a "Home /" option on each page before the category. Below is the code I'm using now. Anyone have any ideas?

```
if ( ! empty( $breadcrumb ) ) {

    echo $wrap_before;

    if ( is_single() && get_post_type() == 'product' ) {

        echo $prepend;

        if ( $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) ) {

            $referer = wp_get_referer();

            $printed = array();

            foreach( $terms as $term){

                if(in_array($term->id, $printed)) continue;

                $referer_slug = (strpos($referer, '/'.$term->slug.'/'));

                if(!$referer_slug==false){

                    $printed[] = $term->id;

                    $category_name = $term->name;
                    $ancestors = get_ancestors( $term->term_id, 'product_cat' );
                    $ancestors = array_reverse( $ancestors );

                    foreach ( $ancestors as $ancestor ) {
                        $ancestor = get_term( $ancestor, 'product_cat' );

                        if ( ! is_wp_error( $ancestor ) && $ancestor )
                            echo $before . '<a href="' . get_term_link( $ancestor->slug, 'product_cat' ) . '">' . $ancestor->name . '</a>' . $after . $delimiter;
                    }

                    echo $before . '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term->slug, 'product_cat' ) . '">' . $category_name . '</a>' . $after . $delimiter;
                }
            }

        }

        echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;

    } else {

        foreach ( $breadcrumb as $key => $crumb ) {

            echo $before;

            if ( ! empty( $crumb[1] ) && sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key + 1 ) {
                echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $crumb[1] ) . '">' . esc_html( $crumb[0] ) . '</a>';
            } else {
                echo esc_html( $crumb[0] );
            }

            echo $after;

            if ( sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key + 1 ) {
                echo $delimiter;
            }

        }
    }

    echo $wrap_after;

}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Why not always printing Home at the start as 'hard coded'? isn't it something trivial to have home at the beginning of a breadcrumbs?

Comment: I would like to have it hard coded from the start, but I don't know php. What would the code be to add that?

Comment: See my solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by changing the following line `echo $wrap_before;` to this:

```
echo $wrap_before.'<a href="/" title="Home">Home</a> »';
```

Comment: Yes, this fixed it!! Thank you so much, I appreciate your help!